# Model refs and Lister

Tags: atk4

I have a question - how can I get and show data from referenced model in Lister?
**referenced table structure (model User):**

> id | login | password | realName | email

**reference logic (Model Post):**

```
$this->hasOne('User', 'author');
```

**template:**

```
Author: <?realName?><?/?>
```

But  is empty, what I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to do this probably is to:

- set realName field as title field (quite logical) in User model
- and simply use that title field in Lister (should be automatically)

So, in User Model you'll have to add:

```
public $title_field = 'realName';
```

And in Lister probably `$lister->setModel($user_model)` should be enough.

**Edit:**
If you want to add field from related model (let's say e-mail) in your grid, then you can use leftJoin in your Post model, like this (not tested):

```
class Model_Post extends SQL_Model{

function init(){
    parent::init();
    // ... define your fields

    // add left join to related TABLE (not model)
    $join_users = $this->leftJoin('user', 'author_id');

    // add field from joined table (not model)
    $join_users->addField('email'); // it's not $this->addField(), but $join->addField() !!!
}
}
```

This will create field email in your Post model and it'll be filled with value from related table.

Comment: ok, but if I want use email from the refed model, how can I do that?